# Передача массива в функцию не обьявляя его

Tags: c++

Как можно передать массив в функцию не обьявляя его?

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(int(&arr)[N]) {
    for (int var : arr)
        printf("%d\n", var);
}

int main(){
    foo( { 1, 4, 5, 6 } ); // <- Ошибка
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может вы хотите передать инициалайзер лист?

Comment: возможно, мне нужно чтобы эти данные попали в функцию

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Проблема вашего кода не имеет никакого отношения к массивам.

Если вы хотите передавать что-то по lvalue-ссылке, то помните, что ко временным объектам разрешается привязывать только *константные* lvalue-ссылки (т.е., выражаясь корректнее, ссылки *на константу*). Нужно только иметь в виду, что в случае массива константность всего массива "проваливается вниз" и становится константностью индивидуальных элементов массива

```
template <size_t N>
void foo(const int (&arr)[N]) {
  ...
```

Это все, что надо исправить в вашем коде.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e98e75636ab73993

Answer (score 6):

```
void foo(std::initializer_list<int> c) {
    for (int var : c)
        printf("%d\n", var);
}

int main(){
    foo( { 1, 4, 5, 6 } ); // <- Ошибка
    return 0;
}
```