# Подать массив в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, объявление

Есть необходимость воспользоваться некоторой функцией. Например:

```
void foo (int * arr) {
    (void) arr;
}
```

Если вызывать её, скажем, так:

```
int arr [] = {1, 2};
foo (arr);
```

то компиляция проходит успешно. Если же написать подобный код:

```
foo ({1, 2});
```

то компилятор выдаст предупреждение `error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void foo(int*)'`. Хотелось в подобном (`foo ({1, 2})`) синтаксисе вызывать функции от массивов, так как, говоря об области применения, хочется задать подобный массив через директиву `#define` и использовать, как константу.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще `#define`? Используйте `const` (или `constexpr`) для создания ваших константных массивов, и сможете передавать их в `foo` не меняя эту функцию.

Comment: Дупликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876878/Передача-массива-в-функцию-не-обьявляя-его

Answer (score 2):

Фактически, вы передаете в функцию временный массив.

В этом случае, вы можете объявить функцию. как шаблонную функцию следующего вида, как это показано в демонстрационной программе ниже.

```
#include <iostream>

#define List1 { 1 }
#define List2 { 1, 2 }

template <size_t N>
void f( const int ( &a )[N] )
{
    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main( void )
{
    f( List1 );
    f( List2 );
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
1 
1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`{}`-список в С++ сам по себе не является выражением, и в контексте инициализации указателя `{}`-список не будет расцениваться как инициализатор для массива. Сделать из него временный массив в таком контексте вы можете только явно

```
  using A = int [];
  A{ 1, 2 }
```

Получаем

```
void foo(int *arr) 
{
}

int main()
{
  using A = int [];
  foo(A{ 1, 2 });
}
```

Замечание: баг в gcc может не позволить вам так неявно получить указатель на временный массив. Тогда `foo((int *) A{ 1, 2 })`.

Но возможно лучше пойти по пути [Передача массива в функцию не обьявляя его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876878/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)